# Multiple threads leading to app force close on Android Device - dont know how they work in

Tags: android

My Debugger shows the following errors in the run cycle of my app:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2598    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2641 
    ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 156    
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1355  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 102    
    Looper.loop() line: 157 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5867    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 858  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 674 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

I don't know what all information you need here so if you need one of my classes, please let me know. I can send the whole code. I really just need to figure this out.

Comment: If the stack trace shows the Main Thread running through performLaunchActivity, then it's usually the `onCreate(Bundle)` callback where whatever it is that goes wrong goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you exactly doing but here are some tips.

Never run long running operation on the main UI Thread. It will freeze your screen or crash your app.

You can instead use a class called AsyncTask or the Handlers..They poth perform long running operations in the background thread,but the result of those operations are posted on the main UI Thread.